# iOS - NSMutableDictionary writeToFile returns YES but plist is not modified

Tags: ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

I am trying to save data in a NSMutableDictionary to a plist. Plist is already in the Resources folder. When I am trying to save the data to the plist using following code it returns YES which means data was successfully saved. But when I check the file data is not saved to it.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userInfo.plist"]; //3
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]){ //4    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"userInfo" ofType:@"plist"]; //5
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }

    BOOL b = [self.userInfoArray writeToFile:path atomically: YES];
    NSLog(@"status %i ", b);
```

Anyone have solution of this ?

Comment: I am sure. I checked by putting a debug point.

Comment: You can't write to the resource bundle.

Comment: And are you 100% certain that the file you are looking at is the same one being written?

Comment: rmaddy - can you explain your answer please

Comment: Why do you copy the plist from the bundle and then immediately overwrite it with the array?

Comment: (And, out of curiosity, what is the return code from `copyItemAtPath`?)

Comment: (And how do you know that the file wasn't modified?  Where are you checking it?)

Comment: @ChaturaM What's to explain? An app's resource bundle is read-only. Write the file to a writable folder. And FYI - precede a user's username with the `@` symbol when you reply to them.

Comment: Your changed file is at "path" of documentsDirectory, not the one in resource bundle. Log the path in console and open finder, command+shift+G, then you will find the changed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was looking at the wrong file. Plist file in the Xcode does not change after saving the data. Instead, plist in the simulator is changing.